# Regular Expression - Add a new line after the found string? (to split a very long string)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to take a LONG single-line text string, and split it up into multiple lines.

For example, take this:

```
<random-text-doesn't-matter-what-this-is><random-text-doesn't-matter-what-this-is><random-text-doesn't-matter-what-this-is><random-text-doesn't-matter-what-this-is>
```

And replace with this:

```
<random-text-doesn't-matter-what-this-is>
<random-text-doesn't-matter-what-this-is>
<random-text-doesn't-matter-what-this-is>
<random-text-doesn't-matter-what-this-is>
```

I can get the first string between < + > using:

```
^[^>]*>
```

But what would I add to **^[^>]*>** to add a line after the first `<random-text-doesn't-matter-what-this-is>` ?

Even better, is there a single pattern that could search all string between < + > and add a new line? The numbers of strings in the long string will increase and decrease so the pattern to add lines on all strings between < + > would need to be totally generic and able to run until the end of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove the beginning of string `^` anchor and search for all instances of `< .. >` ... The `\K` escape sequence resets the starting point of the match *and any previously consumed characters are no longer included*.

```
Find: <[^>]*>\K
Replace: \n
```

Or you could keep it simple I suppose ...

```
Find: (<[^>]*>)
Replace: \1\n
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yE7wY9/2)

Comment: Does `\K` work in N++? I'd suggest keeping it simple and backreferencing: `<[^>]*>` with `\0\n`.

Comment: It works in Notepad++ but I want to run this as a Regular Expression in my Nintex Workflow for SharePoint. I've created some Regex' that work fine, but this step comes back with "Error in regular expression action. parsing "<[^>]*>\K" - Unrecognized escape sequence \K.". Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it means `\K` is not supported, of course could keep it simple. `(<[^>]*>)` and replace `\1\n`

Comment: Really fast thank you - it works as intended. But just not for Nintex Workflows but I've set this as the answer because my context just doesn't support it.